# Overwriting object… is this OK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks, nsarray

Just a general two-part question about class objects.

1) Is it a problem to define an object, say an NSArray or a UIImage, and then overwrite the contents with something else? For example:

```
NSArray *usersInApp=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Barry",@"Horace",@"Marjorie",nil];
...
usersInApp=@[@"Elizabeth",@"Eddie"];
...
NSArray *newUsers=@[@"Beth",@"Axl"];
usersInApp=[NSArray arrayWithArray:newUsers];
```

2) If one instance is set to another (e.g., if the last line were `usersInApp=newUsers;`), does that mean that both variables (`usersInApp`,`newUsers`) will reference the same value?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What makes you think it isn't alright to override a variables value?

Comment: Hi @Popeye, I thought it was likely OK, but wanted to be sure. I suppose my concern was whether Barry, Horace et al would still be stuck in memory somewhere if I overwrote the pointer to them.

Comment: usersInApp = [newUsers copy]; is an easier way to say [NSArray arrayWithArray:...].  Copy might feel inefficient vs. an assignment given @[...] makes an immutable array, but it won't actually 'copy' if unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not overwriting an object at all. You are overwriting pointers to objects (references to objects). And that's absolutely fine.

2. Correct. Both variables reference the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Answers:

1) No.

2) YES.

Question: But why don't you try this yourself with the help of the debugger?

Comment: Hi @dasdom, OK, thanks for confirming this. I've tested this in a variety of apps, but I just wanted to appeal to a variety of people's experiences to see if I missed anything.